# $\alpha$ is closed if and only if $\phi^* \alpha$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

So, I have the following question regarding an exercise from Amann & Escher Analysis 2:

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are open in $R^n$, $\phi \in $ Diff $^q(X, Y)$, and $\alpha ∈ \Omega(q−1)(Y)$ for some $q ≥ 2$, where $\Omega(q−1)(Y)$ is a set of all 1-forms of class $C^{q-1}(Y)$. I need to prove that $\alpha$ is closed if and only if $\phi^* \alpha$ is closed, where $\phi^*$ is a pullback operator (i.e. $\phi^* (\alpha) = \partial\phi(x)^T\alpha(\phi(x))$.

I tried to prove that $\phi$ - closed implies that $\phi^* (\alpha)$ is closed, and I understand that:
\begin{equation}
\phi^* \alpha = \phi^* (\sum_i a_i dy_i) = \sum_i \phi^* (a_i) (\phi^*dy_i) = \sum_i a_i(\phi(x)) \cdot (\sum_k \partial_k \phi^i dx^k) = \\
\sum_k (\sum_i a_i(\phi(x)) \partial_k \phi^i) dx^k
\end{equation}

But I don't see how I can show that $\partial_j \sum_i a_i(\phi(x)) \partial_k \phi^i$ is equal to $\partial_k \sum_i a_i(\phi(x)) \partial_j \phi^i$ if $\partial_k a_j = \partial_j a_k$. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

We have the famous identity $dF^*\beta = F^*d\beta$, valid for any smooth enough map $F : X \to Y$ and smooth enough $k$-form $\beta$ on $Y$, where $d$ is the exterior derivative. To see how smooth is smooth enough, I looked at the definitions. It seems that $s(F^*\omega)$ = $\min(s(\omega), s(F) - 1)$ and $s(d\omega) = s(\omega) - 1$, where $s$ denotes the smoothness class of an object. For the identity to make sense, both $dF^*\beta$ and $F^*d\beta$ need to be of class at least $C^0$. Thus the identity makes sense when $\min(s(\beta), s(F) - 1) - 1 \geq 0$, i.e. $\beta$ is $C^1$ and $F$ is $C^2$.

Also if $G \colon W \to X$, is smooth enough, then $(F \circ G)^*\beta = G^*F^*\beta$. The minimum smoothness requirements are $F, G \in C^1$ and $\beta \in C^0$. With these identities in hand, your claim follows easily since $(\phi^{-1})^*$ "inverts" $\phi^*$.